# Finding a constant in a density function

Tags: probability, piecewise-continuity

> Suppose
>   $$
> f(x)= \begin{cases} 0, & \text{for }x<0, \\ \\ kx, & \text{for } 0\le x < 1, \\ \\0, & \text{for } x\ge1 \end{cases}
> $$
>   is the density of a random variable $X$. How do I find k?

---

The book says the solution is $2$.

I apologize if this is unsolvable, incoherent and/or missing information. This is from my maths schoolbook which is full of such mistakes. I copied the problem as it is.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that the $f$ you have written is a probability density fuction of a random variable $X$. A defining property is that $\int f(x) \; dx =1$ for all pdf's. In our case,
$$
\int f(x) \; dx = \int_0^1 kx \; dx = \frac{k}{2}
$$
and so $k$ must be equal to two.

Comment: What does that symbol before f(x) mean?

Comment: that's an integral . . . if you haven't seen that before you're in the wrong class . . .

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is the density of the continuous random variable $X$. Its distribution function is $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(x)dx$. You must have that the probability of the whole space $\Omega$ is 1 so
$$P(\Omega)=P(X\in\mathbb{R})=\lim_{t\to+\infty}F(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx=\int_0^1kxdx=k/2$$
must equal 1. I.e. $k=2$.

Comment: I think I have found a simpler way to solve it... Since the graph is like a triangle and it's area should be 1, then 1 = (height * width) / 2, and so I have 1 = (1 * k1)/2 , 1 = k/2 , 2 = k. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is the underlying point of both answers.

Comment: @John thanks. This way seems simpler to me since I haven't learnt about the more advanced topics in your answer yet. I will add your answer and the other one along with mine to a final answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler way:

Since the graph is like a triangle and it's area should be 1, then 1 = (height * width) / 2, and so I have 1 = (1 * k1)/2 , 1 = k/2 , 2 = k

> $$\frac{height * width}{2} = 1$$
>
> $$\frac{k1 * 1}{2} = 1$$
>   $$\frac{k}{2} = 1$$
>   $${k} = 2$$

Alternatively, there is a more advanced way suggested by @Jonh

> $f$ is the density of the continuous random variable $X$. Its
>   distribution function is $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(x)dx$. You must have
>   that the probability of the whole space $\Omega$ is 1 so
>   $$P(\Omega)=P(X\in\mathbb{R})=\lim_{t\to+\infty}F(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx=\int_0^1kxdx=k/2$$
>   must equal 1. I.e. $k=2$.

and @user365239

> I'm assuming that the $f$ you have written is a probability density
>   fuction of a random variable $X$. A defining property is that $\int
> > f(x) \; dx =1$ for all pdf's. In our case, $$ \int f(x) \; dx =
> > \int_0^1 kx \; dx = \frac{k}{2} $$ and so $k$ must be equal to two.